# Add CSS to all HTML elements using Javascript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to take CSS selectors, the properties, and values, and add it to HTML using jQuery or Javascript.

What I have tried so far is this:

```
function toggleCSS() {
    var preview = document.getElementById("preview");
    var previewChildren = document.getElementById("preview").querySelectorAll("*"); // Get all of the elements created in the preview from the users HTML input
    var cssToAdd = document.getElementById("cssTextArea").value; // The user is going to type in regular CSS into a textarea, and here I am retrieving the value they typed in

    $(previewChildren).each( function() {
        $(this).css(); // Looping through each node
    });
}
```

Example input:
(HTML)

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>

    <div>
        Hello World!
    </div>

    <div id="TestDiv">
        This is a test!
    </div>
</html>
```

(CSS)

```
#TestDiv {
    background-color: red;
}
```

I am getting stuck on the part of adding the CSS.  I have the raw input in the variable cssToAdd, but how can I translate that CSS to get the Selector and add the properties within that selector to each HTML element?

Comment: Whatever it is you are trying to do needs a far more detailed explanation because currently it's not very clear. Broken code is not a good substitute for a proper explanation

Comment: Well for a start `document.getElementById("preview")` will cause a problem since you have no elements with the `ID` of preview. If you wish ti display an example please ensure it in working order or the javascript is a match for the html.

Comment: @NewToJS The HTML element "preview" has no relevance to the issue.  It would clutter the question if I added everything.

Comment: @charlietfl the issue is I have all of the HTML elements in previewChildren.  I need to loop over all of them, and add CSS to them.  The CSS to add (which is above) is what I need to add.

Comment: @Dom It's an issue here because I have nothing to debug. the element with the `id` of preview is relevant to your question so I suggest you include it and any other relevant elements to go with your javascript.... otherwise how do you expect anyone to expand on it? Or debug it?

Answer (score 1):

if user is inputting proper and complete css  rules just wrap it all in a `<style>` tag and append to `<head>`

```
$('<style>').text(cssToAdd).appendTo('head');
```

Comment: Genius. I'll get back in a minute with my excitement.

Comment: do you know how I could apply this to just my "preview" div instead of the entire internal <style>?

Comment: what do you mean by *"entire internl style"*? might want to look into creating a *"web component"* which isolates style in shadow dom

Comment: What I meant was adding the styles to just the element with the ID "preview" (which is where the above HTML is being displayed inside of).

Comment: if only supporting modern browsers create a web component. some alternatives would be iframe or open a new window

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the value in `cssTextArea` is a well-formed set of css rules pertaining to a single element in `previewChildren`, you can just take the object and pass it to the `css()` function.  You may need to wrap the key and values in quotes:

```
$(this).css({ "background-color": "red", "color":"black",...})
```

See http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-properties

Comment: Do you know of a way I can take my CSS example above (the #TestDiv) and break that apart to get the selector (#TestDiv) and the properties to then add using your above line?

Comment: you can use a multiline regular expression: a quick search here or elsewhere will likely return a suitable solution. If this is for a customer-facing app, I'd recommend a library like [CSSLint](https://github.com/CSSLint/parser-lib)